# Pascal (помогите перевести)

Tags: c, pascal

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float Q1, Q2, R, F;
void main ()
{
    clrscr ();
    const float e = 2.1, e0 = 8.85E-12;

    printf ("Input charge ball= ");
    scanf ("%E", &Q1);
    printf ("Input distation between charge= ");
    scanf ("%E", &R);
    printf ("Input strength= ");
    scanf ("%E", &F);

    Q2 = 4 * M_PI * e * e0 * R * R * F * 0.00001 / Q1;
    printf ("Charge of dust: %E", Q2);

    getch ();
}
```

Comment: @AndreyZiLvova, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся.

Comment: всё уже не сводиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{$N+}
Uses Crt;
Const
     e = 2.1;
     e0 = 8.85E-12;
Var
     Q1, Q2, R, F: Single;
Begin
     ClrScr;
     WriteLn ('Input charge ball = ');
     ReadLn (Q1);

     WriteLn ('Input distation between charge = ');
     ReadLn (R);

     WriteLn ('Input strength = ');
     ReadLn (F);

     Q2 := 4 * Pi * e * e0 * R * R * F * 0.00001 / Q1;
     WriteLn ('Charge of dust: ', Q2);

     ReadKey;
End.
```

Comment: @Ковальский большое спасибо